# PCF conjecture and fixed points of the $\aleph$-function

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals, pcf-theory

Recently Moti Gitik refuted Shelah's PCF conjecture, by producing a countable set $a$ of regular cardinals with $|\operatorname{pcf}(a)| \geq \aleph_1.$ See his papers
 [Short extenders forcings I](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~gitik/se1.pdf) and  [Short extenders forcings II](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~gitik/short%20extenders%20forcing%202-2015.pdf).

In Gitik's model the cardinal $\kappa=\sup(a)$ is a fixed point of the $\aleph$-function.

> **Question.** Can we improve Gitik's result to get a countable set $a$ 
>   of regular cardinals with $|\operatorname{pcf}(a)| \geq \aleph_1$ such that $\kappa=\sup(a)$ is not a fixed point of the $\aleph$-function?

Comment: You should ask Moti directly.

Comment: That would be a huge advance for sure, and much more difficult!

Comment: Mohammed, do you know off hand if the cardinal involved can be the least fixed point?

Comment: @ToddEisworth No, but a few years ago I asked Gitik a related question and he said he's trying to push down the cardinal, but there are many difficulties in doing it. I don't know if he has made any progress on the problem since that time.